# Quitting Putty when GhettoVCB is running

Tags: vmware-esxi, putty, ghettovcb

I am currently backing up 12 VMs from an ESXi 5.1 host using GhettoVCB. I just started the script with Putty. I don't want to have to leave my computer on overnight.

My question is, if I exit out of Putty while the script is running, will GhettoVCB quit also? I have a feeling that the answer is yes, since Putty is directly communicating with the host, but I just need some confirmation.

Comment: You may be interested in a terminal multiplexer such as [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `nohup` utility to prevent process exit on HUP signal